# What is the difference between HttpClient default security protocol in console application and web application

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

While working on a project which requires sending HTTP POST calls to a REST API, I noticed something strange (at least for me) today. First I tested the below code in a console application and it works every time.

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", MY_BASE64_STRING);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api-test.wirecard.com");
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/engine/rest/payments");
request.Content = new StringContent(JSON_REQUEST_STRING, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

But when I put the same code in my web application and test it, it is giving me *The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.* error, with the exact same code and request JSON. After setting the security protocol, it works. The updated code looks like this:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();    
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api-test.wirecard.com");
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/engine/rest/payments");
request.Content = new StringContent(JSON_REQUEST_STRING, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", MY_BASE64_STRING);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; //* new line
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Can anyone tell me what just happened here. I am trying to get the concept behind this. **The 1st code snippet works fine in a console application but not in my web application**. The 2nd works everywhere. Why the console application works without setting Security Protocol.

**Update:**
I ran both of them on the same environment and machine using Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Framework. The web application was launched via IIS Express, inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you run them on the same machine, same .net core runtime versions, and in the same environment? (e.g. was web app running in docker/behind nginx/in IIS etc.)

Comment: @zaitsman Yes. I updated my question with this information.

Comment: Yeah, so most likely you have GP settings or other IIS-specific configuration that causes this. Run the code in .net core kestrel (e.g. raw console based web app) and there probably won't be a difference.

In the second piece of code you specifically state which protocols are allowed for negotiation. There are a number of IIS and Windows settings that allow the admin to disable applications from accessing unsecure protocols (e.g. ssl3 etc). Most likely, this is what you hit.